# React setstate on an array value modifies the value of an array constant

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, setstate

The react component below initializes three input fields. The first two fields are processed as arrays. The value of the first input field is the string defined by value0[0]. The value of the second input field is value0[1]. Keystrokes in either field are appended to the input fields. The value of valueR remains unchanged.

Once the reset button has been clicked, the form no longer works as expected. Keystrokes are still appended to the input field. However, the keystrokes are also being appended to valueR. Since valueR was declared as a constant, this behavior is completely unexpected.

The third input field is processed as a separate state variable. It functions as expected.

Why is there such a marked difference in the behavior of these implementations?

```
import React from 'react';

const value0 = ["First inital value", "Next initial value"];
const valueR = ["1st reset value", "2nd reset value"];
class Foobar extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state         = {valueS: value0, valueS1: '3rd inital value'};
    this.handleReset   = this.handleReset.bind(this);
    this.handleChange  = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleChange1 = this.handleChange1.bind(this);
}
handleReset(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({valueS: valueR, valueS1: "3rd reset value"});
    console.log('reset  '+ valueR);
}
handleChange(e){
    var index = e.currentTarget.id.slice(e.currentTarget.id.length-1);
    var arr = this.state.valueS;
    arr[index] = e.currentTarget.value;
    this.setState({valueS: arr});
    console.log('change '+ valueR);
}
handleChange1(e){
    this.setState({valueS1: e.currentTarget.value});
    console.log('change '+ valueR);
}
render(){
    return (<>
    <form>
    <p>These two input fields are initialized the values in the array value0. 
       As long as the reset button is not depressed, the array valueR retains
       the value created by the const declaration.
    </p>
    <p>
      After the reset button pressed, changes to these two input fields causes
      the valueR array to become assigned to whatever is in this.state.valueS. This is 
      not the expected behavior, as the valueR array is defined as a constant.  
    </p>
    <input id='input0' type="text" value={this.state.valueS[0]} 
        onChange={(e)=>this.handleChange(e)}
    />
    <input id='input1' type="text" value={this.state.valueS[1]} 
        onChange={(e)=>this.handleChange(e)}
    />
    <p>
        This input field is processed separately from the other two input fields.
        Pressing reset set the input field to the string defined in the reset function.
    </p>
    <input  type="text" value={this.state.valueS1} 
        onChange={(e)=>this.handleChange1(e)}
    />

    <br/>
    <button onClick={(e) => this.handleReset(e)}>Reset</button>
    </form>
    <p>
        It is unclear why setState seems to work for a single string and somehow 
        assigns the value of an array of string values to a constant.
    </p>

    </>)
}
}
export default Foobar;
```

Comment: @DrewReese - "...means you can reassign the variable" => should be "CAN'T" :-)

Comment: Did the answer help you solve the problem, @Bruce?

Answer (score 0):

The array in state is the same array that's declared outside. If you proceed to mutate the stateful array (which you should never do in React anyway!), and then log the outside variable array, you'll see that it's mutated too - *since they're the same array*.

Avoid mutating state. Change

```
arr[index] = e.currentTarget.value;
this.setState({valueS: arr});
```

to

```
this.setState({
  valueS: arr.map((val, i) => i !== index ? val : e.currentTarget.value
});
```